# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 when creating a chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sharepoint

I am trying to draw a chart from a list on a SharePoint web page. The list looks something like this:

```
Title                  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May ...
Salaries and Wages     100  400  300  500  700 ...
MIP                    800    0    0  900   50 ...

Payroll Tax Expense      0    0    0  300   40 ...
Contract/Temp Labor    200  100    0    0    0 ...
...                    ...  ...  ...  ...  ... ...
```

I would like to draw a line graph showing month-to-month variability using the Title entries as legends. Ultimately, the list should look like this:

```
        Salaries and Wages   MIP  Payroll ...
Jan                    100   800        0 ...
Feb                    400     0        0 ...
Mar                    300     0        0 ...
...                    ...   ...      ... ...
```

And the data passed in to draw the line graph:

```
[1, 100, 800, 0]; 
[2, 400, 0, 0];
[3, 300, 0, 0]
```

Here is what I have so far. Notice I am retrieving the data using JQuery commands from a list on my site.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','line']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

        var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Month');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Salaries and Wages');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'MIP');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Payroll Tax Expense');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Contract/Temp Labor');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Recruitment');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Severance');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'SIP');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Relocation');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Other Bonuses');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Benefits Expense');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Other (People)');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Employee Welfare');
 datatable.addColumn('number', 'Overtime');

var uri = "https://company.com/sites/ITAppDev/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Take Two')/items?$select=Title,OData__x0032_016_x0020_Plan_x0020_F1,OData__x0020_Jan_x0020_Actuals_x0020_,OData__x0020_Feb_x0020_Actual_x0020_,OData__x0020_March_x0020_Actual_x0020_";
 $.ajax({
           url: uri,
           type: "GET",
           async:false,
           data: JSON.stringify(datatable),
           cache:true,
           headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
           success: function (data)
                 {                                
                       var dataResults = data.d.results;
         var month = 0;
          var monthData = [];
         for (j=1; j<dataResults.length; j++)
    {
     month = parseInt(j);
                                        console.log(month);
                                        monthData[0]=month;
     for (i=0; i<data.d.results.length; i++)
     {
      var date = dataResults[i].OData__x0020_Jan_x0020_Actuals_x0020_;
      monthData[i]=date;
     }
    datatable.addRows([monthData]);
    }
                       console.log(monthData)
                 },
             error: function (data)
             {
                  console.log("error!")
                  var dataResults = data.d.results;
                  console.log(dataResults)
             },
                 });

var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Popularity'
        },
        colors: ['#a52714', '#097138']
      };

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
        chart.draw(datatable, options);
      }
    </script>

<div id="chart_div2"></div>
```

After running the code, I get an error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404". I suspect that 
    `data: JSON.stringify(datatable)`

is the issue, because I am stringifying a datatable which contains no rows (because there is no list with those columns on my site). I do want to stringify the original list so that I can manipulate the results in an array format, but I also want to turn the original list into a transposed list without creating another list on the site. Is there any way around this?